# Proving $ z^n + \frac{1}{z^n} = 2\cos(n\theta) $ for $z = \cos (\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> > Question: Prove that if $z = \cos (\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$, then
> >
> > $$ z^n +  {1\over z^n} = 2\cos(n\theta) $$

---

What I have attempted

If $$  z = \cos (\theta) + i\sin(\theta) $$

then $$ z^n = \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta) $$

$$ z^n +  {1\over z^n} $$

$$ \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta) +  {1\over \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)} $$

$$ (\cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta))\cdot(\cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)) + 1 $$

$$ \left[ {(\cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta))\cdot(\cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)) + 1\over \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}  \right]  $$

$$ \left[ {\cos^2(n\theta) + 2i\sin(n\theta)\cos (n\theta) - \sin^2(n\theta) + 1\over \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}  \right]  $$

Now this is where I am stuck.. I tried to use a double angle identity but I can't eliminate the imaginary part..

Comment: It seems as if you know de Moivre's Formula. This formula is also valid for negative exponents (as a consequence of the formula for $n\geq0$), so writing $\frac{1}{z^n}$ as $z^{-n}$ will lead directly to what you want.

Comment: Ah yes , thanks... that was easier than expected..

Comment: From the 3rd. line of your demonstration, it seems you have missed the fact that the reciprocal of a complex number with unit modulus is its conjugate..as Guest says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to continue in the way you started, you can simply rewrite $1=\cos^2(n\theta)+\sin^2(n\theta)$ and then simplify:
$$
\frac{\cos^2(n\theta) + 2i\sin(n\theta)\cos (n\theta) - \sin^2(n\theta) + 1}{ \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}=
\frac{\cos^2(n\theta) + 2i\sin(n\theta)\cos (n\theta) - \sin^2(n\theta) + \cos^2(n\theta)+\sin^2(n\theta)}{ \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}=
\frac{2\cos^2(n\theta) + 2i\sin(n\theta)\cos (n\theta)}{ \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}=
\frac{2\cos(n\theta) (\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))}{ \cos (n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}= \underline{\underline{2\cos(n\theta)}}
$$

Which shows that you were almost there. (But it is still useful that you posted your question here - you have seen other approaches.)

Answer (score 11):

setting the value of $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, $$z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$$$$=z^n+z^{-n}$$
$$=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n+(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{-n}$$
Using d-Moivre's theorem, 
$$=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)+\cos(-n\theta)+i\sin(-n\theta)$$
$$=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)+\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)$$
$$=2\cos(n\theta)$$

Comment: Whys is it that the negative sign for cos(−nθ) does not negate cos(nθ) itself but for isin(−nθ) it does?

Comment: Because graph of $\cos\theta$ is symmetric about Y-axis hence  $\cos(-\theta)=\cos\theta$

Comment: Thank you @Harish!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. If $$z=\cos (\theta) + i\sin(\theta)= e^{i\theta}$$ then
$$
\frac1{z^n}=z^{-n}=e^{-in\theta}=\cos (n\theta) - i\sin(n\theta).
$$

Answer (score 6):

Using geometry of complex:
[image]

By construction, point $C$ corresponds to $z^n$ an $C^\prime$ to $z^{-n}$. i.e. $\beta=-n\theta$ (the symmetry of the image is due to the fact that $|z|=1$, and thus $z\overline{z}=1$). Then $z^n+z^{-n}$ is, interpreting as a sum of vectors, the vector $\vec{OD}$. Then, by means of Cosine Law's, it is easy to conclude.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: To simplify $\dfrac{1}{\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)}$, multiply top and bottom by $\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without recalling the [De Moivre's formula](https://De%20Moivre%27s%20formula%20is%20a%20precursor%20to%20Euler%27s%20formula)... Olivier Oloa used it but didn't recall the [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $e^{ix}=\cos x+ i\sin x$. From this, we have $e^{-ix}=\cos x- i\sin x$ and hence $2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$ and $2i\sin x=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$.

Now, we have a quick computation for OP's question:
$$\large z^n+z^{-n}=(e^{i\theta})^n+(e^{i\theta})^{-n}=e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}=2\cos n\theta.$$

Comment: +1 for this nice answer

Answer (score -1):

We know that any complex number can be written in polar form as:

z = r(cosθ + i sinθ)

where r is the modulus of z and θ is its argument.

Now, we can write:

z^-1 = 1/z = 1/r(cos(-θ) + i sin(-θ)) = cos(-θ)/r - i sin(-θ)/r
= cosθ/r + i sinθ/r

Using this, we have:

z + z^-1 = r(cosθ + i sinθ) + r(cosθ/r + i sinθ/r)
= r(cosθ + cosθ/r) + i(sinθ + sinθ/r)
= r(cosθ + cos^2θ/r + sin^2θ/r) + i(sinθ + sin^2θ/r + cosθsinθ/r)
= r(1 + cosθcos(x) + sinθsin(x)) + i(sinθ + cosθsin(x))
= 2r cos(x + θ)

where we have used the identity cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b) - sin(a)sin(b) with a = θ and b = x.

Now, since z is a non-zero complex number, its modulus r is also non-zero. Therefore, we can divide both sides by 2r to obtain:

z + z^-1 = 2 cos(x + θ)/2 = 2 cos(x)

and the proof is complete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use $ symbols...

Comment: -1 for your unclear answer